# Как перекодировать "Такую" строку в обычный питоновский str()?

Tags: python, кодировка

```
u"\u043b\u043e\u043c, \u0432\u044b\u0440\u0435\u0437\u043a\u0430, to scrap, \u043e\u0442\u043a\u0430\u0437\u0430\u0442\u044c\u0441\u044f"
```

Как её перегнать в Питоне в обычный str() ?

Я могу позвать print:

```
>>> print s
лом, вырезка, to scrap, отказаться
```

Но если просто зову дамп s:

```
>>> s
u'\u043b\u043e\u043c, \u0432\u044b\u0440\u0435\u0437\u043a\u0430, to scrap, \u043e\u0442\u043a\u0430\u0437\u0430\u0442\u044c\u0441\u044f'
```

И в str загнать не могу:

```
>>> str(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Вот чего я добился:

```
>>> for i in xrange(0,len(s)): print i, s[i], ord(s[i])
0 л 1083
1 о 1086
2 м 1084
3 , 44
4   32
5 в 1074
6 ы 1099
7 р 1088
8 е 1077
9 з 1079
10 к 1082
11 а 1072
12 , 44
13   32
14 t 116
15 o 111
16   32
17 s 115
18 c 99
19 r 114
20 a 97
21 p 112
22 , 44
23   32
24 о 1086
25 т 1090
26 к 1082
27 а 1072
28 з 1079
29 а 1072
30 т 1090
31 ь 1100
32 с 1089
33 я 1103
```

Похоже что переформатировать из utf-8 в ascii читаемый вебом, лучше всего так:

```
>>> str(s.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace'))
'&#1083;&#1086;&#1084;, &#1074;&#1099;&#1088;&#1077;&#1079;&#1082;&#1072;, to scrap, &#1086;&#1090;&#1082;&#1072;&#1079;&#1072;&#1090;&#1100;&#1089;&#1103;'
```

Comment: json_decode попробуй=)

Comment: вот так как то parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich, тут чего-то не заметно json строки.

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich, он ничего не делает со строкой, даже если дорисовать скобочки {, }, и т.д. Он всего лишь дампит эту строчку и всё. Формата нет.

Comment: =) ну ладно тогда вот так https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich, благодарю, Ваша ссылка помогла, если оформите как ответ - я зачту.

Comment: @encoder да не =) я даже питон не знаю

Answer (score 2):

`u''` -- это текстовое представление Юникодной строки (неизменяемая последовательность символов) в Питоне 2, где тип `str` используется для байтовых строк (неизменяемая последовательность байтов).

При работе с текстом следует использовать Юникод и поэтому ничего с `s` делать не нужно.

Если нужно преобразовать заданный текст в байты, например, чтобы по сети передать как двоичные данные, то можно использовать `s.encode(character_encoding)`, например: `sock.sendall(s.encode(utf-8))`.